# Issues with implementing tile-snap movement system in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’m working on incorporating tile-based movement for my character, aiming to have the character aligned with the next tile in the direction of movement. Currently, there’s an issue where the player is consistently snapped to the top and right cells, irrespective of the input directions. As a consequence, when I move the character left or bottom, it snaps to the right or upper cell, rather than the next one in the intended direction. I’m utilizing the new player input system.

> Current logic:
>
> The target grid position is calculated based on the current player position (rb.position) divided by the gridSize. This gives the grid cell that the player is currently in.
> The center of the next tile in the movement direction is calculated by adding the movementInput vector to the target grid position.
> The rb.MovePosition method is then used to smoothly move the player towards the calculated center of the next tile. It uses Vector2.Lerp to interpolate between the current position and the target position.
> nextTileCenter * gridSize converts the grid position back to world space.
> new Vector2(gridSize / 2, gridSize / 2) is added to ensure that the player moves to the center of the next tile.

```
`script:

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public float snapSpeed = 10.0f;
    public LayerMask collisionLayer;

    Vector2 movementInput;
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator animator;
    Transform gridTransform; // Reference to the grid game object

    bool canMove = true;
    float gridSize = 0.16f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        // Find the grid game object
        gridTransform = GameObject.Find("Grid").transform;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
    if (canMove)
    {
        // Get raw input without normalization
        Vector2 rawInput = movementInput;

        // Normalize the input vector to limit diagonal movement
        movementInput = new Vector2(Mathf.Round(rawInput.x), Mathf.Round(rawInput.y)).normalized;

        if (movementInput != Vector2.zero)
        {
            // Calculate the target position on the grid
            Vector2 targetPosition = CalculateTargetPosition(rb.position, movementInput);

            // Check for potential collisions
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(targetPosition, Vector2.zero, gridSize, collisionLayer);
            if (hit.collider == null)
            {
                // Move towards the target position using Rigidbody2D.MovePosition()
                rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movementInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                // Player hit something, try to snap to the grid smoothly
                SmoothSnapToGrid();
            }

            animator.SetBool("isMoving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            // Player is not moving, try to snap to the grid smoothly
            SmoothSnapToGrid();

            animator.SetBool("isMoving", false);
        }

        // Set direction of sprite to movement direction
        if (movementInput.x < 0)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
        }
        else if (movementInput.x > 0)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
        }
    }
}

    private void SmoothSnapToGrid()
    {
        // Calculate the target grid position
        Vector2 targetGridPosition = new Vector2(
            Mathf.Round(rb.position.x / gridSize),
            Mathf.Round(rb.position.y / gridSize)
        );

        // Calculate the center of the next tile in the movement direction
        Vector2 nextTileCenter = targetGridPosition + movementInput;

        // Smoothly move towards the center of the next tile in the movement direction
        rb.MovePosition(Vector2.Lerp(rb.position, nextTileCenter * gridSize + new Vector2(gridSize / 2, gridSize / 2), snapSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    private Vector2 CalculateTargetPosition(Vector2 currentPosition, Vector2 direction)
    {
        // Calculate the target position based on the movement direction
        Vector2 targetPosition = currentPosition + direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        return targetPosition;
    }

    void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
{
    Vector2 rawInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
    float horizontal = Mathf.Round(rawInput.x);
    float vertical = Mathf.Round(rawInput.y);

    // Ensure only one direction is considered
    if (Mathf.Abs(horizontal) > Mathf.Abs(vertical))
    {
        movementInput = new Vector2(horizontal, 0f).normalized;
    }
    else
    {
        movementInput = new Vector2(0f, vertical).normalized;
    }
}


    public void LockMovement()
    {
        canMove = false;
    }

    public void UnlockMovement()
    {
        canMove = true;
    }
}`
```

Anyone could help with that please?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***Mathf.Round*** function rounds to the nearest integer, which means if the player's position is exactly in the middle of two cells, it might not round to the expected direction. This could be causing the consistent snapping to the top and right cells.

To address this, you can modify the **SmoothSnapToGrid** method to account for the direction of movement when calculating the target grid position. Instead of using ***Mathf.Round***, you can use ***Mathf.Floor*** or ***Mathf.Ceil*** depending on the direction of movement:

```
private void SmoothSnapToGrid()
{
    // Use Floor or Ceil depending on the direction to ensure snapping to the correct cell
    Vector2 targetGridPosition = new Vector2(
        (movementInput.x > 0) ? Mathf.Floor(rb.position.x / gridSize) : Mathf.Ceil(rb.position.x / gridSize),
        (movementInput.y > 0) ? Mathf.Floor(rb.position.y / gridSize) : Mathf.Ceil(rb.position.y / gridSize)
    );

    // Calculate the center of the next tile in the movement direction
    Vector2 nextTileCenter = targetGridPosition + movementInput;

    // Smoothly move towards the center of the next tile in the movement direction
    rb.MovePosition(Vector2.Lerp(rb.position, nextTileCenter * gridSize + new Vector2(gridSize / 2, gridSize / 2), snapSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

This change ensures that when moving left or down (movementInput.x < 0 or movementInput.y < 0), Mathf.Ceil is used to get the upper bound, effectively snapping to the left or bottom cell. Conversely, when moving right or up (movementInput.x > 0 or movementInput.y > 0), Mathf.Floor is used to snap to the right or top cell.

Additionally, it's important to make sure that your OnMove method is correctly setting the movementInput. If you're experiencing issues with diagonal movement or want to ensure only one axis of movement at a time, your current implementation seems correct.

Finally, always ensure that your grid size (gridSize) matches the actual size of your tiles in the game world. If there's a mismatch, it could lead to incorrect snapping.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer. Now the player is moving towards the upper right corner, when I go into the game mode. I tried to reset movement input, but nothing really helps.

Comment: Additionally Round sometimes might not round as expected at all .. see [rounding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-8.0#midpoint-values-and-rounding-conventions)

Comment: @derHugo do you have any suggestions what is the best way around it?

Comment: I made some changes and this worked, thank you! 
I will now need to tweak it a bit to make it a bit more natural. Thank you!